# Preflight requests (OPTIONS) failing for local vapor project

Tags: swift, vapor, preflight

I've created a basic backend written in Swift using the Vapor framework. I am running it locally on my machine, so it can be reached at `http://localhost:8080`.
For the project I'm working on, I'm also building the frontend, which is built using ReactJS and can be reached at `http://localhost:3000`.

When calling my backend in **Postman**, with the following info, the request works fine and the user is created in the database:

**Method**
POST /user

**Headers**
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

**Body**

```
{
    email: "email@example.com
    password: "12345"
}
```

Now, when calling that same method with the same body & headers from within the local frontend, my request immediately fails, without any response:

[image: failed response]

When I inspect the response, I see that all body & headers were sent properly, but there was no response.
I googled a little and realized that Postman (& similar) behave differently than browsers and that I should check whether the method works with `OPTIONS`, instead of `POST`. I called the method again: `OPTIONS /user` and it failed in Postman as well:

[image: failed options call]

The only difference is, in Postman, I receive a response, being *"Result not found"* as you can see in the screenshot.

I thought, it may have something to do with `localhost` in the API call's url, since the frontend is also running on localhost. So I used ngrok to forward my port 8080 (backend) and then called the `*.ngrok.io` url, instead of `localhost:8080`. No luck.
I also tried using my machine's network IP address, instead of `localhost`. Still no luck.

What can I do about this?

Comment: Options preflight request are usually emitted to check wether Cross domain request (CORS) are allowed, are they enabled on your backend?

Comment: @lazizanie see my updated post

Comment: try let corsConfiguration = CORSMiddleware.Configuration(
    allowedOrigin: .all,
    allowedMethods: .all,
    allowedHeaders: .all
)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you configure your backend's CORS settings as follows, it should work:

### Vapor 4

```swift
let corsConfiguration = CORSMiddleware.Configuration(
    allowedOrigin: .all,
    allowedMethods: [.GET, .POST, .PUT, .OPTIONS, .DELETE, .PATCH],
    allowedHeaders: [.accept, .authorization, .contentType, .origin, .xRequestedWith, .userAgent, .accessControlAllowOrigin]
)
app.middleware.use(CORSMiddleware(configuration: corsConfiguration))
```

### Vapor 3

```swift
let corsConfiguration = CORSMiddleware.Configuration(
    allowedOrigin: .all,
    allowedMethods: [.GET, .POST, .PUT, .OPTIONS, .DELETE, .PATCH],
    allowedHeaders: [.accept, .authorization, .contentType, .origin, .xRequestedWith, .userAgent, .accessControlAllowOrigin]
)
middlewares.use(CORSMiddleware(configuration: corsConfiguration))
services.register(middlewares)
```